# Dynamically changing HTML text breaks jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace

I have some portion of HTML on my site, whereby when the user makes a selection, aspects of the HTML text changes.

Meaning - when the user makes a selection on, say, a checkbox, some text within a specified `div` is modified.

However, I am unable to execute scripts whenever the HTML has been modified. The pertinent IDs and classess within this DIV are unchanged, and other untouched HTML will trigger the script just fine. What is it about the HTML after it's been programmatically altered, makes it not trigger the script?

The code I'm referring to is:

```
<input type='checkbox' id='switch'>Switch text
<div id="example">
    <input type='checkbox' class='trigger' id='box1'>Text Text AAA
    <input type='checkbox' class='trigger' id='box2'>Text Text AAA
    <input type='checkbox' class='trigger' id='box3'>Text Text AAA</div>
```

JS

```
$('#switch').change(function () {
    if ($('#switch').is(':checked')) {
        var str = $('#example').html().replace(/AAA/g, 'Hello');
        $('#example').html(str);
    }
});

$('.trigger').change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        alert('It worked');
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L82r45ob/

Comment: are you seeing the error in the fiddle you provided? Because everything appears fine to me

Comment: The "error" is that as written, my JS will not show the alert after the HTML is dynamically changed - for the reason #dfsq mentions below. No actual error is reported in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you replace HTML with `html` method:

```
var str = $('#example').html().replace(/AAA/g, 'Hello');
$('#example').html(str);
```

it removes all bound event handlers. Hence the issue.

Use event delegation instead:

```
$('#example').on('change', '.trigger', function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        alert('It worked');
    }
});
```

In this case you attach event to the `#example` div which never changes, so you benefit from event bubbling up the DOM tree.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/L82r45ob/1/

Comment: Ahhh, thank you very much for that nice explanation. I didn't realize that triggering the event from the changed items removes the bound event handlers.

Comment: No-no, when you overwrite HTML content with `html` method (innerHTML = '...') it removes event handlers.

Comment: Oh, I see now. I didn't realize `html` actually overwrites the loaded HTML content. Thanks.